# User Info on Case History

Tags: soql, case, history-tracking, field-history

I am trying to pull the user (person who made the change) via SOQL query on cases. This is not a "standard" field in the API Developers guide for `CaseHistory` but it is available for standard history reports.  Here is my current query to pull all available fields.  Any suggestions on how to add the user that made the changes?

```sql
SELECT CaseId, DataType, Field, NewValue, OldValue, ID FROM CaseHistory
```

Answer (score 1):

For any field history record, the user who made the edit to the parent record, is the user who created the field history record. So you can use `CreatedById` to get the user id, use relationships to get more information about the user (ie `CreatedBy.Name`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOQL like below to fetch the Last Modified User name:

```
SELECT ID, Subject, Type,LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, (SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories) FROM Case
```

The child history relationship name is called "Histories".

Learn More [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_associated_objects_history.htm)